# How can I add a scalar to a matrix in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix

Am trying to use the quadratic function while simultaneously multiplying an the identity matrix of 5.

```
fivemat = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}

mySol[a_, b_, c_] := Solve[a x^2 fivemat + b x fivemat + c == 0, x]
```

However, when I do the following:

```
mySol[1,2,3]
```

It returns:

```
Out[]={}
```

Thank you

Comment: Question title should really be: "How can I add a scalar to a matrix in Mathematica?"

Comment: @QuantumDot changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a unit matrix:

```
mySol[a_, b_, c_] := Solve[a x^2 fivemat + b x fivemat + c IdentityMatrix[5] == 0, x]
```

Now it works:

```
mySol[1,2,3]

Out[3]={{x -> -1 - I Sqrt[2]}, {x -> -1 + I Sqrt[2]}}
```

Comment: Thank you why what exactly happened here? Still lost on why that last one IdentityMatrix[5] was needed?

Comment: Matrices can only be added to other matrices and not to scalars.

Comment: Okay thank you. I was helping a friend solve a problem. He desired the problem to be in essence like this it was written aM^2*I+bM*I+c = 0. But what you are saying here he may have forgotten to add the last matrix.

Comment: Since `fivemat == IdentityMatrix[5]` this is just `mySol[a_, b_, c_] := 
 Solve[(a x^2 + b x + c) IdentityMatrix[5] == 0, x]` or `Solve[(a x^2 + b x + c) == 0, x]`